# The use of BOF model in Stanford NER?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I found a description in the FAQ page of stanford NER https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html, which says that 'Processing is done using a bag of features model, with all of the features mixed together, which is why it is important to not have any name conflicts.' at the bottom of first question. But I can't find the specific usage of BOF model in the feature process stage.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Where the BOF model is used, or which java file in the source code has used this model? And why use this model? Thx!